# No puedo abrir modal automáticamente de varios productos

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
   const mostrarProductos = (stockProductos) => {
    contenedorProductos.innerHTML = ``

    stockProductos.forEach( (producto) => {
        const div = document.createElement('div')
        div.classList.add('producto')
        div.innerHTML = `
        
        <img class="imagenCelular" src="${producto.img}"" alt="">
        <h3 class="nombreCelular">${producto.nombre}</h3>
        <button class="buttonVerProducto">Ver Producto</button>


        <div class="modalProducto" style="display: none;">  
            <img class="imagenCelular" src="${producto.img}"" alt="">
            <h3 class="nombreCelular">${producto.nombre}</h3>
        </div>
            
        ` 
        contenedorProductos.appendChild(div)
        
        $('.buttonVerProducto').on('click', function () {
            $(".modalProducto").css("display","block");
        })


    } )

}
```

La idea es que al darle click a "buttonVerProducto" se muestre el "modalProducto", el problema está en que al seleccionarlos con jquery por su clase se abren/muestran todos al mismo tiempo. Pensé en usar un array y meter los modales para luego iterarles con un bucle for un id único para cada uno, pero no sé bien como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un identificador único para asociar el botón del producto al modal con sus datos.

Si el producto tiene ID, puedes usar este, sino usa una función que genere cadenas aleatorias de p.e. 9 caracteres, cada modal de producto y botón de producto con la misma.

Supongamos que tienes un ID de producto (debe ser único), genera un HTML como este:

```
<section class="product">
    <img class="imagenCelular" src="${producto.img}"" alt="">
    <h3 class="nombreCelular">${producto.nombre}</h3>
    <button class="buttonVerProducto_${producto.id}">
        Ver Producto
    </button>


    <div class="modalProducto_${producto.id}" style="display: none;">  
        <img class="imagenCelular" src="${producto.img}"" alt="">
        <h3 class="nombreCelular">${producto.nombre}</h3>
    </div>
</section>
```

Añades un escuchador de evento para cada botón de cada producto:

```
$('.buttonVerProducto_' + producto.id).on('click', function () {
    $(".modalProducto_" + producto.id).css("display","block");
})
```